# Eliminar los márgenes del cuerpo de la pagina

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de averiguar cómo eliminar los márgenes que aparecen por arriba y por abajo de mi texto en el ejemplo, sin embargo solo con css no encuentro soluciones.

```css
body {
  margin=0;
  padding=0;
}
.paco {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class=paco>AGITA PACO</div>
```

Comment: puedes explicar el problema, ya que ninguna de las 2 respuestas (ambas correctas) te sirvio?

Comment: quise decir ambas correctas frente a la explicación que diste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intente definiendo el `margin` y `padding` del `body`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

.paco{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class=paco>AGÜITA PACO</div>
```

Comment: Y no funciona; será que no es posible?

Comment: que no funciona ? definiendo los margenes del body quitas los espacios superior y lateral

Comment: Sigue habiendo píxeles negros entre las letras y el espacio blanco; por arriba y por abajo.

Comment: pixel negro ? estas definiendo el background:black; o sea el fondo del div es negro

Comment: me parece que ya se a lo que te refieres, pero creo que ese espacio es propio de la fuente de texto. Si cambias por ejemplo a font-family:verdana veras como ese espacio al menso el superior cambia

Comment: Entiendo, dejaré un rato abierta la pregunta y si nadie responde la cerraré. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy seguro de que si pones esto te servirá.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.paco {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div >
    <p>asdasdsd</p>
    <p class=paco>AGITA PACO</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ibas bien, pero hay un error en tu código: Estas utilizando `=` en lugar de `:` para asignar el valor de los margenes y el relleno (padding).

la sintaxis correcta seria:

```
body {
  margin: 0; /* no uses el = aquí, usa los : */
  padding: 0;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.paco {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class=paco>EL ROCK AGITA LA LOMA</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad CSS "line-height" indica el espacio entre líneas de un texto, quizás te sirva usando un número menor de 1.
Luego hay el "padding" y el "margin" del contenedor, pero entendí que ya lo miraste.